# What's the point of titles in Tales of Vesperia?

Tags: tales-of-vesperia

I'm a few hours into playing Tales of Vesperia, and I noticed that each of my characters has a few titles to choose from in the Status screen. Does the active title affect gameplay/stats? Does it make cosmetic differences? Or is the only purpose of titles to be fun to collect?

By titles, I mean things like

> Downtown Boy and Basic Swordsman for Yuri; Man's Best Friend and Dog Warrior for Repede

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this [Tales of Vesperia titles guide](http://www.gamefaqs.com/xbox360/945075-tales-of-vesperia/faqs/54229), titles can affect your outfit but not your stats.  There is also an achievement for getting all of the titles in the game.

Comment: Okay, I tried all of my titles, and they had no effect on my stats. Either Vesperia doesn't work like Symphonia, or I just need to get farther into the game.

Comment: @Lord Torgamus - Bingo.  It doesn't work like Symphonia.

Comment: I should probably add, for those showing up late, that my first comment was a response to the first revision of this answer, and made a lot more sense when it was posted. (@Shinrai)